# Hacer un filtro de fechas en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde tengo el campo fRegistro es de tipo datetime, quisiera convertirlo en date para poder usarlo en un where y en un bteween.

Este es mi código en SQL

```
SELECT e.idExpediente,u.nombres,u.apellidos,u.correo,e.descripcion,e.fRegistro from expediente e inner join usuario u on e.id_user = u.idUser WHERE CONVERT(date,fRegistro) = '2021-05-04'
```

Comment: Utilizo SQL Server

Comment: No me muestra ningún registro

Comment: Del mismo modo que haces un convert para la fecha de la base de datos, debes de hacer un convert para la fecha de la comparación.

Comment: No necesitas usar funciones de fecha para este caso, esto podría neutralizar los índices y provocar un cálculo en cada fila, teniendo un impacto negativo en el rendimiento ([ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25564544/5587982)), Puedes simplemente hacer esto: `WHERE fRegistro => '2021-05-04' AND fRegistro < '2021-05-05'` o, si usas SQL Server 2008+ `CAST` es la mejor opción: `WHERE CAST(fRegistro AS DATE) = '2021-05-04'` ([ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25564539/5587982) para más detalles sobre la optimización en este caso).